# Call a method that will run in the background while the original thread finishes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Service that is called when an endpoint in my API is hit. In the Service, I add the object to a list, and then call a new method which should sleep for a certain amount of time, and then update the object which was just added to the original list. The issue is that i need the POST that started the thread to finish and return a status code while the time delay is still going on. At the moment, my POST is still waiting for the delay method to finish.

Any ideas if this is possible to do?

**Create Service**

```
List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();

public async Task<dynamic> Create(Object obj)
{
    var newObj = new Object()
    {
        Id = obj.Id,
        Name = obj.name,
        Status = obj.Status
    };

    objList.Add(newObj);

    ChangeState(newObj.Id);

    return newObj;
}
```

**ChangeState Method**

```
public async void ChangeState(string objId)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        var objState = objList.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == objId);

        objState.State = "APPROVED";
    }
```

Comment: what kind of effect does `async void` have according to you? I'd say queue the work but unless you wait it is impossible to return the updated object. Can you describe the actual use case because just blocking the thread for 5 seconds does not seem production code to me.

Comment: I suggest you start looking into [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl). The TPL library uses threading underneath and makes working with threads alot easier. For example you can start a Task and not await it, which will result in your desired funcionallity

Comment: @PeterBons exactly, it is not production code. It's mocking an external API that i am going to hit, the object will be accepted and return an accepted status to me, but only after a certain amount of time will its state become approved (Polling to check state). It could be the case that i hit the endpoint multiple times before the first object is approved. Any ideas?

Comment: First let me ask you this: in the current code the updated object (with the changed state) is returned. Do you accept that that will no longer be the case if the update of the status is done in the background?

Comment: @PeterBons I want to return the old object, with the old status first. Then, after the waiting period, the object's status will be updated, and the Get endpoint which is being polled will then show the object with the updated status.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your service lives long enough to make this meaningful:

```
List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();

public dynamic Create(Thing obj)
{
    var newObj = new //i assume you meant to create an anonymous type here
    {
        Id = obj.Id,
        Name = obj.name, //public things should be PascalCase
        Status = obj.Status
    };

    objList.Add(newObj);

    _ = ChangeStateAsync(newObj.Id); //set it going and discard the result; it'll complete 4.9999999999 seconds after this method finishes

    return newObj;
}
```

And

```
public async Task ChangeStateAsync(string objId)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    var objState = objList.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == objId);

    objState.State = "APPROVED";
}
```

ps;

```
    class Thing
    {
        public string Id;
        public string name; //public things should be PascalCase
        public string Status;
    }
```